# Proper organization of Javascript "class" files

Tags: javascript

In my javascript application I have a "class", as well as a mixin object. The class uses the mixin object. So, I have a file called, `mixinObject.js`, which defines the mixin:

```
var mixinObject = {
    mixinMethod1: function(){},
    mixinMethod2: function(){}
}
```

I have a separate file defining "class", like so:

```
var myClass = {
    classProp: true,
    classMethod: function(){},
}

_.extend(myClass.prototype, mixinObject);
```

Should this `extend` line be in the file defining the `myClass` object, or is there a "better" way to do this so that only the class definition is in the `myClass` file?

Comment: FYI: the second example will error. It needs to be `var classProp = true` or `this.classProp= true`.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error, fixed.

Comment: I would leave it in the same file since, I will then know that I am explicitly extending the mixin.

Answer (score 2):

There can be two cases here.

1. The class needs the mixin object everytime the class is initialized(mixin is a dependency).
2. It needs the mixin only in certain cases.

If it is case 1, then you can add the extend in the class file because you dont need to extend it before every class initialization.

If it is case 2, you can extend the mixin only in the files that you need the mixin functions.